# Angular Animations with ng-repeat, always fire off ng-enter on array change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-animation

I have an array list I'm filtering with a text field and ng-repeat. The animations I'm using for ng-enter are very simple (a fade in), however when I press backspace on my search query ONLY the filter items load in and it looks buggy. Is there a way I can make the entire list fade back in (reset the ng-enter on all items to fire off ).

Maybe I just reset my array? Or jumble it? Is there a better way to fire off ng-enter on the entire list?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior sounds correct to me. Why would you like to fade in items that have not been removed? It might confuse the user that the items which didn't disappear suddenly fade. Maybe if you posted a gif it would be easier to give an answer.

Comment: I forgot to mention I am staggering the animation. The behavior is correct but if I remove/filter a large chunk of my list and then press backspace (making those filtered items come back) they jump in from top to bottom, excluding the ones that were never filtered out. I'd rather re-animate the entire list

Comment: So your problem is the order changes? Adding `track by` to your `ng-repeat` definition might help: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates